# Why is this dynamic HTML5 video thumbnail generation failing in IE11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-11

I have a Javascript function setup to dynamically generate thumbnails from a given embedded HTML5 video once it loads. This works fine on other browsers. The problem arises with IE11. For some reason, it's just not outputting anything despite working perfectly on Firefox and Chrome.

I have a section of the site which has several HTML5 videos and they need to generate their respective thumbnails based on the first frame. I've done a good bit of researching around and I can't seem to find any IE11 compatibility issues with my code.

Here is the code I have now:

```
var vids = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=video-]');  

for(var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++){
   if(vids[i].tagName == 'VIDEO'){
      $("#video-" + (i+1)).on("loadeddata", generate_handler(i+1));
   }
   ...
}
```

`generate_handler` calls the `shoot` function (had to do it this way because of scoping issues in the loop),

```
function generate_handler(j) {
        return function(event) { 
            shoot(j);
        };
}
```

and the `shoot` function goes as follows:

```
function shoot(num){
    var video  = document.getElementById('video-' + num);
    var output = document.getElementById('videothumbnail-' + num);
    if(output.childNodes.length == 1){
        var canvas = capture(video);
        output.appendChild(canvas);
    }
}
```

and finally, the `capture` function is as follows:

```
function capture(video) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var w = 48;
    var h = 40;
    canvas.width  = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    canvas.style.marginTop = "4px";
    canvas.style.width = w + "px";
    canvas.style.height = h + "px";
    canvas.style.zIndex = "-999";
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
    return canvas;
}
```

Essentially, as a TL;DR: When the data of the video is loaded, it calls this function to shoot a screengrab and add it to the thumbnail div. In order to do that, it draws the video to a canvas. This is the order the functions are called:

`on('loadeddata', generate_handler())` -> `shoot()` -> `capture()`

What's strange is that after some simple tests with `console.log`, it actually is reaching the inside of `capture()`, which inclines me to believe it's a compatibility issue with something in there, or with `appendChild()`.

What this should do (and does do on Firefox/Chrome) is draw a 48x44px thumbnail of the HTML5 video being loaded on the page. Instead, on IE11 it displays nothing.

Comment: What does `generate_handler()` do?

Comment: @j08691 updated the post with it. It was just my workaround for scoping problems in the loop. It's just a way to call the `shoot()` function.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `debugger` statement or breakpoint to step through it?

Comment: Try to use developer tools and check whether canvas tag is added to the HTML or not and verify that you had appended it to the correct div which is exist on the web page. for testing purpose, try to remove the num variable from get element by id and check the output.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT checked it - it's creating the canvas to the proper dimensions and appending to the correct id. Looks like it might be having issues with drawing the image if that's the case?

Comment: Are you making the test on a local machine? If yes, Than I suggest you to host your code on any web server and than try to run the same code will work for Internet Explorer.